# Django post data not save in admin DB

Tags: python, html, django

I want my form data save in the DB but it doesn't work
Additionally how can i save that post data in my computer?(if this question is not clear, you can ignore)

view.py

```
class task_generation_view(FormView):
    form_class = TaskGenerationForm
    model = TaskGeneration
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = "task_generation.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('data_upload')
```

models.py

```
class TaskGeneration(models.Model):
    classification = '분류 알고리즘'
    regression = '회귀 알고리즘'
    clustering ='군집화 알고리즘'
    detection = '이상치 탐지 알고리즘'
    reinforce ='강화학습 알고리즘'
    SELECT_ALGORITHM_CHOICES = (
        (classification, '분류 알고리즘'),
        (regression,'회귀 알고리즘'),
        (clustering, '군집화 알고리즘'),
        (detection, ' 이상치 탐지 알고리즘'),
        (clustering,' 강화학습 알고리즘'),
    )
    algorithm = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices = SELECT_ALGORITHM_CHOICES, default = classification)
    readyData = models.BooleanField()
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    #url('$', ModelingView_model.as_view()),
    url('task_generation', task_generation_view.as_view()),
    url('data_upload', data_upload_view.as_view(), name='data_upload'),
    url('data_load', data_load_view.as_view()),
    url('data_exploration', data_exploration_view.as_view(), name='data_exploration'),
    url('data_variable_Identification', data_variable_identification_view.as_view()),

    # url('', FileUploadView.as_view(), name='upload'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

forms.py

```
class TaskGenerationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskGeneration
        fields = ('algorithm', 'readyData')
        widgets ={
            'algorithm' : forms.Select(attrs = {'class' : 'btn btn-info btn-select btn-select-light'}),
        }
```

task_generation.html

```
 <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.algorithm }}
...
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.readyData }}
<button type="submt">submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does jsp have to do with anything? And why do you want to save a file? Where are you having problems?

Comment: sorry i edit my question, my problem is save data in admin site does not work.

Comment: But you don't seem to have written any code to save the data.

Comment: if you dont mind can you point where i modify or add code?

Comment: In the view. For a start, you could try inheriting from CreateView rather than FormView.

Comment: thanks i try it, it works! but i dont know how make css in create view..haha
but really thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the class-based view `task_generation_view` in `views.py` was inheriting from the wrong class. It should extend `CreateView` instead of `FormView`. I'd suggest reading more on CBVs on the Django documentation website [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/).